# Update expression for a list of maps in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I have the following DynamoDB table:

```
{
    record_id: Decimal(10),
    ...,
    options: [ # This is a List of maps
       {option_id: 1, counter: Decimal(0), ...},
       {option_id: 2, counter: Decimal(0), ...}, 
    ],
    ...
}
```

Which consists of some items, with unique `record_id` and the target `options` list. That list contains maps. In those maps, there is an `option_id` attribute, and I would like to access the item in the `options` list whose `option_id` equals to some target `my_option_id` and increment its counter.

For example, for the above example, given `my_record_id=10` and `my_option_id=2`, I would like to update the second option item, with `option_id=2`, and increment its counter by 1, so this `{option_id: 2, counter: Decimal(0), ...}` becomes `{option_id: 2, counter: Decimal(1), ...}`.

I am using Python and boto3, but I imagine the syntax here is specific to DynamoDB. Here is what I have so far:

```
    response = table.update_item(
        Key={
            'record_id': my_record_id,
        }, 
        UpdateExpression='SET options.#s.counter = options.#s.counter + :val',  
        ExpressionAttributeNames={
            "#s": my_option_id
        },  
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':val': Decimal(1)
        },
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the easy fix was to make `options` a map instead of a list, and then make the `option_id` the key of that map. Then my code works as expected:

```
response = table.update_item(
    Key={
        'record_id': my_record_id,
    }, 
    UpdateExpression='SET options.#s.counter = options.#s.counter + :val',  
    ExpressionAttributeNames={
        "#s": my_option_id
    },  
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':val': Decimal(1)
    },
    ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
)
```